# Dynamically REVOKE CONNECT FROM guest in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I wrote this simplistic script (I'm not very familiar with TSQL and dynamic SQL) to revoke all connections from guest accounts:

```
DECLARE @database_id int, @database_name nvarchar(100);

DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM [master].sys.databases
WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb')
AND state = 0

OPEN database_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor
INTO @database_name

while (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
        BEGIN
                Print @database_name
                exec('USE [' + @database_name + ']')

REVOKE CONNECT FROM 'guest'

                FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor
                INTO @database_name
        END

CLOSE database_cursor
DEALLOCATE database_cursor
```

But apparently the REVOKE was still being applied to the master database.

So then I modified the script to this:

```
DECLARE @database_id int, @database_name nvarchar(100);

DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM [master].sys.databases
WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb')
AND state = 0

OPEN database_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor
INTO @database_name

while (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
        BEGIN
                Print @database_name
                EXEC('USE [' + @database_name + '];'+

'REVOKE CONNECT FROM GUEST;'

                    );

                FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor
                INTO @database_name
        END

CLOSE database_cursor
DEALLOCATE database_cursor
```

The script runs, but the changes aren't be saved for some reason because the guest account is not revoked when I check for it afterwards.

Sorry, if I'm missing any other details.  I'm so unfamiliar to this realm, I'm not even sure how to frame the question.

Thanks in advance!

Update 1:
I'm checking that it's been revoked using this script from the DISA STIGs:

```
SELECT COUNT(grantee_principal_id)
FROM sys.database_permissions
WHERE grantee_principal_id = 2
AND state = 'G'
AND permission_name = 'CONNECT'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your script with no problems so my guess is that something is wrong with your conformation script.  I don't see anything specifically wrong with it but here are a couple of links with additional information about disabling guest.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/02/24/sql-server-guest-user-and-msdb-database-enable-guest-user-on-msdb-database/

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/02/20/sql-server-disable-guest-account-serious-security-issue/

Here is a a modified version of Pinal Dave's script that should help you confirm.

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?];
    SELECT ''?'' DBName, name, permission_name, state_desc
    FROM sys.database_principals prin
    INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions perm
        ON prin.principal_id = perm.grantee_principal_id
    WHERE name = ''guest'' AND permission_name = ''CONNECT''';
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, disabling guest account in master, msdb and tempdb is not advisable. For references and additional information; please read the below linked articles.

From SQL*Server [BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189438.aspx)

- The guest user cannot be dropped, but guest user can be disabled by revoking its CONNECT permission by executing REVOKE CONNECT FROM GUEST within any database other than master or tempdb.

And also from the following [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2539091)

- SQL Server Books Online recommends that you disable the guest user in every database as a best practice for securing the database server. This recommendation does not apply to master, msdb, and tempb system databases. In order for some Microsoft SQL Server features to work, the guest user must be enabled in the msdb database. This article describes some issues that you may experience if you disable the guest user in the msdb database. The article also provides information about how to resolve those issues.

Comment: I guess you meant to say that the OP needs to exclude `msdb` from the list of databases on which the script operates, in addition to `master` and `tempdb` that are already being excluded.

Comment: @sqlchow: Thanks for the input.  And yes, I'm trying to apply this change on databases other than master and tempdb.  I can add msdb to the list also, but that's not helping me verify that the changes have or have not been applied.  Thank you for your time! :)